# Silverlight App works in VS debug but not published

Tags: silverlight

I have a very basic silverlight application that allows for data edits (from a SQL Server database) on a form.  The application works great if I debug it from Visual Studio, but if I publish it to an IIS server, then the form loads, but the data on them does not.  I get the error:

> "Message: Unhandled Error in
>   Silverlight Application Load operation
>   failed for query
>   'GetItcLoadTransactionsForLoadDate'.
>   The remote server returned an error:
>   NotFound.   at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.OperationBase.Complete(Exception
>   error)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.LoadOperation.Complete(Exception
>   error)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.CompleteLoad(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.<>c_*DisplayClass1b.b*_17(Object
>   ) Line: 1 Char: 1 Code: 0"

Any ideas what My issue could be.  I am a complete newb with silverlight, and IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your endpoints for any services are pointing at your deployment site and not your debug server. Also, ensure you have a [`crossdomain.xml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28VS.95%29.aspx) or [`clientaccesspolicy.xml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28VS.95%29.aspx).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107131/silverlight-webservice-call-works-in-studio-but-fails-when-run-from-website/5107220#5107220) for additional information.

Comment: OK, just to show how newbish I am, I can't even find a reference to the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file. I had simply created some Domain Services around some Entity Framework entities, and everything was created for me.

Comment: I tried to add both the crossdomain.xml and the clientaccesspolicy.xml, but they did not do anything for me.  I don't think that I am crosssing networks or domains as I run this on our development server.

Comment: You will have to edit the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig yourself. They are auto-generated for you anyway. Look in your project files on the actual hard disk.

Comment: Make sure that the crossdomain.xml and clientaccesspolicy.xml are available on the same port as your application. I had to publish my application on the port 80 in order to enable the cross domain policies. Other ports can also be used but it's more tricky.