# silverlight wcf call working locally but not from remote host

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, wcf, silverlight-4.0

i have a silverlight application that is hosted within a asp.net web application. in the web application there is a wcf service defined. silverlight uses this service.
when the silverlight application runs locally, everything works fine. when the application is deployed to my server, the application itself loads, but loading the data from the wcf service fails.

application is hosted on virtual private server running on port 1900. port 1900 configured for inbound and outbound traffic at the firewall. when i access the appilication from within the server, it works. when accessing it from another host, loading the data via wcf fails.

Comment: i think that this post solves my problem. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107131/silverlight-webservice-call-works-in-studio-but-fails-when-run-from-website)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really sounds like a same-origin fail.

Check to verify that both the silverlight.xap file and the wcf endpoint are:
- on exactly the same domain (www.mydomain.com != mydomain.com)
- using exactly the same protocol (http/https)
- using exactly the same port number (1900 in your example)

If not, you can use the [crossdomain.xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) file to work around it.